# creating continuous heatmap on a square figure for a dataset with uneven length of x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any ways to fit a dataset with uneven length of x and y on a square figure for creating a continuous heatmap?

The dataset has a dataset of 10 rows (y axis) by 1000 columns (x axis). My intention is to plot a continuous heatmap and this heatmap should be a square using ggplot2.

Here is the example:

```
df<- data.frame(matrix(runif(10000,1,100), nrow=10))
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what you are asking for. In general, default `heatmap` and `heatmap.2` functions will plot a square figure. So in your case the cells would be taller than they are wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the data into long format. You can use `melt` function from `reshape2` package to do it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

m <- matrix(runif(10000, 1, 100), nrow=10)
ggplot(melt(m), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

You can change the plot into square by `ratio` argument in `coord_fixed`.

```
# Adjust the ratio
ggplot(melt(m), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=value)) + geom_tile() +
  coord_fixed(ratio=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make the plot in a square?

Comment: You means the whole plot as a square or the individual cell as a square?

Comment: You can use `coord_fixed` to adjust the plot. I am updating an example.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Two last questions: (1) how to reverse the Y axis (i.e., 0 is on the top and 10 in on the bottom of Y axis)? (2) how to apply rev() to m[1,], m[3,], m[5,], m[7,], m[9,] and then form a new data frame for plotting? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use `scale_y_reverse()` to reverse Y axis.

Comment: and this may work for 2): `m[, seq(1, 9, 2)] <- apply(m[, seq(1, 9, 2)], 2, rev)`  . Then you can use the same way to transform the data.